# Using the Camera Data Node

Tags: node-editor

In the blender manual the options for [camera data node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/materials/nodes/types/input/camera_data.html?highlight=camera%20data) are explained like this:

> **View Vector**
>
> A Camera space vector from the camera to the shading point.
>
> **View Z Depth**
>
> How far away each pixel is from the camera
>
> **View Distance**
>
> Distance from the camera to the shading point

[image]

So, what is the shading point? How is each of these options different form the other, and in which cases should one be used instead of the other?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111070/how-to-emulate-camera-distance-in-cycles-node-system

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132827/camera-data-view-vector-interpretation

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Shading Point**

is the ***nearest point of intersection*** of the camera ray with a visible object, which the render engine is currently calculating the color for (these calculations are referred to as shading)

### [image]

**The real View Vector**

it is a vector (or a ray) in the camera space, starting from the center of the camera (or the view) and reaching the shading point

[image]

---

**View Vector**

it is a ***normalized view vector*** (magnitude = 1 or unit vector) in the camera space, starting from the center of the camera (or the view) and pointing at the shading point (it doesn't necessarily reach it )

[image]

---

**View Z Depth**

- it is the ***Z component of the view vector*** (the non normalized)
- it is the shortest distance from the shading point to the camera's XY plane (the is not normalized Z-depth, it is not from 0 to 1)

[image]

---

**View Distance**

it is the magnitude of the non normalized view vector, or simply the distance from the shading point to the camera's center

[image]

---

where to use each one: well you know enough now to decide where to use them!