# Apply depth transparency to array object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, modifiers, node-editor

Can I fade in transparency of a material based on distance to camera when the object is part of an array of objects? It seems that they only use the original object's location attributes. However when I apply modifiers the material still won't attenuate based on ray depth?
[image]

I am trying to fly through the array objects, but I want to fade them in gently as I go so that they don't 'pop' into view.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that! But you didn't make an answer so I can't upvote it :(

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27764/using-the-camera-data-node

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the camera data node and a color ramp to control the transparency.

[image]

[image]

Note that you might need to increase the transparency bounce settings for the  Light Paths to prevent artifacts.

[image]

Or you might want to try controlling the transparency through the Ray length on the Light Path:

[image]