# Make some particular objects' colours change according to their distance from camera

Tags: camera, transparency

There is a way to fade all objects into transparency according to there distance from the active camera ([Apply depth transparency to array object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45125/apply-depth-transparency-to-array-object)).

I'd like to achieve the same affect but only for some objects (in my case, text objects, that I would like to show only as camera approaches, so that the view is not cluttered by the hundreds of text objects in my scene). Is this possible without animating the transparency of each object? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/76946/29586 - use distance from camera to mix between normal material and transparent.