# Vector for Camera Direction

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I know that one can use a *Gradient* texture and *Texture Coordinates* node to fade an object out the farther it is away it is along an axis. They can even use a *Mapping* or *Separate XYZ* node to change the direction of the fade.

#### However

Using a *Mapping* node can be tedious, especially in an animation. I was wondering if it was possible to fade an object out away from the camera direction via a straight up *Vector*/*Input* node output or a combination of *Vector*/*Input* nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use camera distance instead, that way it dynamically adjusts transparency relative to camera position dynamically.

Just use the *Input > Camera Data* node instead. Some math nodes to adjst the factor may be needed.

[image: Camera Data Node]

Comment: I had seen the _Camera Data_ node, but I couldn't get it to work. Thanks! Also, how does that _Divide_ node affect things? What is it dividing? Lastly, I tried replacing the _Ambient Occlusion_ node with a _Diffuse BSDF_, but the results weren't as good. Why would _Ambient Occlusion_ work better?

Comment: The math node is dividing the actual distance from the camera to the object in Blender Scene units. You'll have to adjust it according to your scene's size and desired threshold distance. Replacing the ambient occlusion with any other shader should have no effect on the setup whatsoever, I just used the ambient occlusion because it is fast to render and requires no lighting, making it simpler to post here

Comment: related: [Using the Camera Data Node](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27764/using-the-camera-data-node)

Answer (score 0):

The aforementioned one way that I figured out produced a result like this. By default, it aligned the vector with the center of the camera's view.

*View 1:*

[image]

*View 2:*

[image]

*View 3, with later-mentioned* Mapping *node modifications:*

[image]

*Node setup:*

[image]

The *Fac:* vector setup works by utilizing the *Texture Coordinate* node's *Object* output. I obviously selected the camera as the object. I then used a *Mapping* node because the Z-rotation was off. The divide can be moved up and down by adjusting the *Mapping* node's *Location:* values. I found *X:* to be particularly effective.