# How to make a fixed texture/"End Portal Effect"?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, eevee-render-engine

I was wondering if this would first off, even be possible within Blender. I wanted to make a project where I have a characters eye textures follow where the camera goes.

I can't think of too many example except for [Minecraft's End portal](https://youtu.be/UwWoIwo1p0U?t=115), and [League of Legend's Cosmic Reaver Kassadin skin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1m8-_sxYc0)

I'm guessing these both are more for game engine side of things, but I was wondering if it can be done in Blender.

Also bonus points if anyone can tell me what the effect is called! (I tried looking up "fixed texture", but alas, nothing)

Comment: Are you after a portal effect or eyes to follow a camera - a character's gaze following you about?

Comment: I think you could use the camera vector in the node editor.... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53648/vector-for-camera-direction or if it has to be fixed in space use the location of an non-moving empty in node editor

Comment: I want the portal effect but for a texture, not another scene. It's just going to be a star texture like in both the examples. Also I will try and experiment with that later today and update the post if I can figure it out.

Comment: its called the monalisa effect named after the effect that the painting has with the eyes following you around the room