# How to use camera distance to mix textures?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

i want to show some textures when the camera is closer to the object and not when it is far, so how can i do this in cycles. is there any particular node to do this trickery or any work around?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27764/using-the-camera-data-node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [**camera data**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/materials/nodes/types/input/camera_data.html?highlight=camera%20data) node to control the mixture of two nodes (color mix or shader mix).

Mix nodes expect information on the 0 to 1 scale, so the distance information will need to be scaled somehow or you need to define a threshold for the transition.

As an example: With a math node in "Less Than" or "More Than" mode you can create a distance threshold for the transition.

[image]

For a more subtle transition you can use a gradient texture:

Notice that you can usel Z depth as well and use a multiply node to control the transition point.

[image]

And for more control a color ramp.

[image]

For more info read : [Using the Camera Data Node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27764/using-the-camera-data-node)

Comment: yeah exactly what i was looking for